# Insert map key as an id inside map value

Tags: flutter, dart

My goal is to insert a map key as an id inside map value (which is also a map, the nested one).
Say I have a map as follows

```
  Map<String, dynamic> userMap = {
    "id_1" : {
      "name": "John",
      "surname": "Doe",
      "age": 25,
    },
    "id_2" : {
      "name": "Jeremy",
      "surname": "Smith",
      "age": 42,
    }
  };
```

I want to convert this to

```
  Map<String, dynamic> userMap = {
    "id_1" : {
      "id": "id_1",
      "name": "John",
      "surname": "Doe",
      "age": 25,
    },
    "id_2" : {
      "id": "id_2",
      "name": "Jeremy",
      "surname": "Smith",
      "age": 42,
    }
  };
```

I tried this

```
userMap.entries.map((entry) => (entry.value as Map).putIfAbsent('id', () => entry.key));
```

but it is not working. Instead it is giving result as `(id_1, id_2)`. What I am doing wrong ?? Is there any way to achieve the desired one ??

Answer (score 2):

> ```dart
> userMap.entries.map((entry) => (entry.value as Map).putIfAbsent('id', () => entry.key));
> ```

The reason why that doesn't work is because you don't do anything with the result of calling `.map()`.  From the [`Iterable.map` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Iterable/map.html):

> Returns a new lazy `Iterable`.... As long as the returned `Iterable` is not iterated over, the supplied function `f` will not be invoked.

Your callback function thus is never called and will not mutate the original `Map`.  You *could* forcibly iterate over the result of `.map()` (e.g. `userMap.entries.map(...).toList()`) to get your desired result.  However that's wasteful and misuses `Iterable.map`.

`Iterable.map` is meant to be used to perform a *functional transformation* on an `Iterable`; you should *not* use it when the callback has side effects. (A "side effect" is something that the callback does other than just `return`ing a value.) For callbacks where you care about side effects, either use `Iterable.forEach` or use a normal `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
userMap.forEach((k,v) => {(v as Map).putIfAbsent('id', () => k)});
```

Comment: well thanks.. but i'm still curious what is going wrong with my method..

Comment: The `MapEntry` instances that the `map.entries` returns are final, so you can't change them. @SatyajyotiBiswas

Comment: @Mobina `final` does not prevent mutation, and you *can* mutate `map` via `map.entries`.